# How to send a string as a parameter of an API method through URL which contains '+' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular 4. Here I am trying to pass a string to an API call .
Currently I just assigned the sequence of characters to a string variable and passed it to an API URL .

Here the problem is when I receive the string in API it loses the + in the string and each + is replaced by a space .

So how should I pass the string which has the + symbols in it to the API.

app.component.ts

```
var isValidString = "AhU29yCXdtoaNyQ8rhUBZMz0MieMNBTUaaA04hO+pGzd/iK01sQx6ckMi8LqCdyphShlBt9QhLtCizcUsy708eU90GD7Qg==";
            this.CartdataService.validateString(isValidString).subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
            });
```

Here the string has a + in it ,which is not present when I receive it in my API function.

Angular.Service:

```
validateString(isValidString){
  return this.http.get(this.validate_User_Password_URL = this.SERVER_URL+`/api/ECOMAPI/validateUserPassword/?mValidateString=${validateString}`);
}
```

In API

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> validvalidateUserPassword(string myString)
        {
          if (myString) != " ")
          {
            .............
          }
       }
```

While debugging the myString the string has the space instead of +

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: You could use `encodeURIComponent`. But afaik you need not to depending on how you pass that string to your angular http call. Can you paste that part, too?

Comment: please check the updated post @Matt

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, please upvote and mark one of the answers as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the encodeURI and decodeURI

```
var encoded = encodeURI(uri);
```

Your code

```
var isValidString = encodeURI("AhU29yCXdtoaNyQ8rhU+pGzd/i......");
// now call the service method with above encoded string
```

Move to your API Code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))
{
    myString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myString);
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: still I receive the string which don't have + in API @AliAdravi

Comment: You probably mean `encodeURIComponent`. `encodeURI` does not encode the plus symbol, see the paragraph "Not escaped" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried url encoding the string and check if it works?
You can use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode special characters.

```
var isValidString = "AhU29yCXdtoaNyQ8rhUBZMz0MieMNBTUaaA04hO+pGzd/iK01sQx6ckMi8LqCdyphShlBt9QhLtCizcUsy708eU90GD7Qg==";
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(isValidString);

// then append the encoded one to the url instead of the original string
```

Comment: still I receive the string which don't have + in API @Binbo

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that if you use HttpParams instead of assembling the string by yourself, Angular does the encoding stuff for you. Something like this

```
let str = "adam+eve"
let params = new HttpParams().set("isValidString", str);
return this.http.get("http://foo.bar", {params}) as Observable<Any>
```

should result in a call to

> http://foo.bar?validString=adam+eve